# vb.net how to export pdf from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, pdf, datagridview

i manage to link the mssql get the data and generate to pdf. But now i have a problem in i only can get my sql database header row, others data row cannot be show. any suggestion to solve this problem. Sorry for my english ,hope can uderstand my question.

this is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
Dim sDs As DataSet
Dim sTable As DataTable

Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server= SHQN080-0116; Database= HKT ;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM SalArea"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "SalArea")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("SalArea")
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("SalArea")
    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    save_btn.Enabled = False
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

End Sub
Private Sub export_btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles export_btn.Click
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount)
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

    'Adding Header row
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
        cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240)
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
    Next

    'Adding DataRow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())
        Next
    Next

    'Exporting to PDF
    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\PDFs\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        stream.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Export to Docx then transform the Docx to PDF

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply, I hope this helps someone.  The error in the code is that you are referencing the .value property of the cell, when you should be referencing the .formattedvalue of the cell.  Here is the code

```
Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount)
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

    'Adding Header row
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
        cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
    Next

    'Adding DataRow
    Dim cellvalue As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            cellvalue = cell.FormattedValue
            pdfTable.AddCell(Convert.ToString(cellvalue))
        Next
    Next

    'Exporting to PDF
    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\PDFs\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        stream.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```